# How to add individual sets of tick-marks on the same axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a figure that has 'inout' major tick marks and 'in' minor tick marks. However, given length=8 for major tick marks and length=4 for minor tick marks, the side of the major tick marks that points in are equal in length to the minor ticks. If I double the length of the major tick marks, I get the desired length pointing in, but am left with marks pointing out that are too long.

Basically I am trying to have major tick marks that point in with length 8 and major tick marks that point out with length 4. I have tried creating a secondary x-axis with ax.secondary_xaxis('bottom'), that handles the side that points in. However, that gets overwritten by the code that follows, which sets the major marks in the usual way and sets direction to 'out'.

Perhaps there is a way to offset the major marks? I could see setting length=12 and having an offset of 1/3 as something that would work. Otherwise, I need a way of defining two separate sets of marks.

### [Colab Example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oPmcFT2eekO0zBazIUVGW5e5gOqjNeKs?usp=sharing)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([],[])
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.tick_params('both', length=8, width=1, which='major', direction='inout', pad=10.)
ax.tick_params('both', length=4, width=1, which='minor', direction='in')

ax_t = ax.secondary_xaxis('top')
ax_t.minorticks_on()
ax_t.set_xticklabels([])
ax_t.tick_params(which='minor', axis='x', direction='in', length=4)
ax_t.tick_params(which='major', axis='x', direction='in', length=8)

ax_r = ax.secondary_yaxis('right')
ax_r.minorticks_on()
ax_r.set_yticklabels([])
ax_r.tick_params(which='minor', axis='y', direction='in', length=4)
ax_r.tick_params(which='major', axis='y', direction='in', length=8)


ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)

plt.show()
```

### Current Output

- The plot is almost what I am looking for. The issue is that the side of the major tick marks that point in on the left and bottom side are equal in length to the minor tick marks.

[image]

Comment: @r-beginners code added to question

Comment: Add additional information by using the [edit] link below the question. All code should be included in the question.